# Как обернуть функцию декоратором?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Есть функция

```
def startInvRej(self, event): 
    if 2 < event.button < 4:
        self.canvCoor = []
        self.frameCoor = []
        print(event.x)
        print(event.xdata)
        self.frameCoor.append(event.x)
        self.canvCoor.append(float(event.xdata))
        print(self.frameCoor)
        print(self.canvCoor)
```

Как завернуть ее в декоратор, чтобы функция выполнялась с отладочным выводом (т.е. с print'ами), если это необходимо, а иначе без него?

---

После Ваших ответов и недолгих раздумий было решено сделать таким образом:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapped(self, event):
        print(event.x)
        print(event.xdata)
        func(self, event)
        print(self.frameCoor)
        print(self.canvCoor)
    return wrapped

@decorator
def startInvRej(self, event):
    if event.button ==3:
        self.canvCoor = []
        self.frameCoor = []
        self.frameCoor.append(event.x)
        self.canvCoor.append(float(event.xdata))
```

Насколько этот способ корректен? И объясните, пожалуйста, почему такой способ работает несмотря на то, что я написал `func(self, event)`, а не `startInvRej(self, event)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не могу не порекомендовать встроенный модуль [logging](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html)

Пример из [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging.html):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Выведет в указанный файл:

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
INFO:root:So should this
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

Запускаете своё приложение с ключом `--log=INFO` и наслажлаетесь фильтрованным логированием.

Если задача именно в освоении декораторов, можно сделать супер-тупо:

```
# Заглушка, которая не выводит ничего
def log_print_stub( *args, **kwargs ):
    pass

# глобальная переменная, с помощью которой
# вызывается либо функция print для логгирования,
# либо log_print_stub, чтобы ничего не делать
log_print = log_print_stub

# декоратор, изменяющий состояние глобальной переменной
# перед вызовом декорируемой функции
def logged(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        global log_print
        log_print = print
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        log_print = log_print_stub
        return result
    return wrapped

# пример:

@logged
def show_log( message ):
    print( "show_log" )
    log_print( message, " ", message )

def dont_show_log( message ):
    print( "dont_show_log")
    log_print( message, " ", message )

# декорированная функция выведет "Видно Видно"
show_log( "Видно" )
# не декорированная ничего дополнительно не делает
dont_show_log( "Не видно" )
```

Считаю этот метод супер-тупым, так как глобальные переменные - зло. Кроме того, теоретически, этот метод непотокобезопасен.

Answer (score 2):

Если честно, тут очевидного применения декоратора я не вижу, может потому что не так часто ими пользуюсь, но всё же. А почему бы не попробовать вот так:

```
def startInvRej(self, event, debug=False): 
    if 2 < event.button < 4:
        self.canvCoor = []
        self.frameCoor = []
        if debug:
            print(event.x)
            print(event.xdata)
        self.frameCoor.append(event.x)
        self.canvCoor.append(float(event.xdata))
        if debug:
            print(self.frameCoor)
            print(self.canvCoor)
```

Там ведь достаточно очевидно и просто всё выглядит :)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он в принципе логичен, но дело все в том, что при использовании декоратора пришлось бы просто убрать знак # с #@decorator и функция выполнялась бы с print'ами. 
Я начинающий питонщик и могу где - то ошибаться конечно. И на самом деле хотелось бы разобраться с декораторами на примере.

Comment: Я Вас понял, но могу привести контрпример. А если Вы хотите программно как-то влиять на вывод с print'ами или без. Но это я так, просто как один из вариантов. Для изучения декораторов самый очевидный пример - это сделать декоратор, который будет считать время, которое выполняется функция. Попробуйте, можете еще на хабр посмотреть на тему декораторов, там было много сильных постов на эту тему.