# Задача на создание декоратора для функции

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

Условие задачи:

```py
def transform(list1, list2):
  result = []
  for i in list1:
     for j in list2:
        result.append(f"{i} + {j}")
  return result
```

Cоздать декоратор, который, при применении его к вышеописанной функции,
вернет список, получаемый при вызове transform(), но в обратном порядке
(перевёрнутый список).

Вот мои попытки:

```
#исходная функция
def transform(list1,list2):
    result = []
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            result.append(f'{i} + {j}')
    return result
```

Дальше идет моя попытка создать декоратор. Как можно заметить, я не дошел до того, чтобы задать ему какое-либо применение. Я попытался делать по аналогии с сайта, чтобы понять алгоритм, но что-то пошло не так. Я создал обертку чтобы мне было понятнее, как работает декоратор. Но в итоге я получал вот это [<function my_new_decorator..the_wrapper_around_the_original_function at 0x10cd4c940>]
То есть результата как такового нет.

```
def my_new_decorator(transform):
     # Внутри себя декоратор определяет функцию-"обёртку". Она будет обёрнута вокруг декорируемой,
     # получая возможность исполнять произвольный код до и после неё.
     def the_wrapper_around_the_original_function():
         print("Я - код, который отработает до вызова функции")
         transform() # Сама функция
         print("А я - код, срабатывающий после")
     # Вернём эту функцию
     yield the_wrapper_around_the_original_function
a = my_new_decorator(transform([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]))
print(list(a))
```

P.S. я новичок и плохо разбираюсь в этой теме, но очень хочу научиться. Буду признателен тем, кто откликнется.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обернуть функцию декоратором?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238774/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1):

```
def rev(fn): # принимаем декорируемую функцию
    def inner(*args): # фактически вызываемая после декорирования функция
        return fn(*args)[::-1] # вызываем с теми же args, реверсим, возвращаем
    return inner
```

Применить для однократного вызова:

```
res = rev(transform)([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
```

Или, на постоянной основе:

```
@rev
def transform(l1, l2):
    result = []
    # ...
```

Comment: Вы бы не могли объяснить поподробнее ваше решение и как конкретно его применить к исходной функции?

Comment: Нет, вряд ли. Я вполне подробно объяснил решение(см. комментарии) и показал оба известных мне способа применения декоратора к исходной функции.